# Iterating through security groups and pulling usernames without duplicate results

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a Powershell script that I wrote that iterates through Active Directory security groups and pulls the names of the users in those groups then exports them to a CSV file. The problem is that some users are in multiple groups and need to be in those groups so when the script runs it creates duplicate entries in the CSV file. Here is the code:

```
$(foreach ($Group in $GroupArray)
{
  Get-ADGroupMember $Group | select name 
  

   
}) | Export-Csv -Path "E:\Software\Powershell Scripts\KB4\KBList.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

I have tried adding a -Unique to the end of select name so it would look like this:

```
$(foreach ($Group in $GroupArray)
{
  Get-ADGroupMember $Group | select name -Unique
  

   
}) | Export-Csv -Path "E:\Software\Powershell Scripts\KB4\KBList.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

I have also tried re-importing the CSV, pushing out a list to the console of Powershell filtering out duplicates using Select-Object then re-exporting it to a CSV however that doesn't generate anything in that CSV. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Your `select -unique` is just in the wrong place. Try moving it to `) | Select -Unique | Export-Csv...`. You might also want to use `Get-ADGroupMember $Group | select -Expand name` so you get an array of strings, not an array of object, where each object has 1 property: 'Name', where the value of that property is the name of each person.

Comment: Yes that is correct, the group samAccountName's are in that array.  I'm looking for the users that are a member of that group.  @TheMadTechnician I tried both of your suggestions.  The first one just gave me the name of one user, while the second suggestion gave me a list of numbers.

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing the foreach loop to a one line code of: ```$GroupArray | Get-AdGroupMember | Select-Object -Property Name -Unique | Export-Csv -Path "E:\Software\Powershell Scripts\KB4\KBList.csv"```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not use `Get-ADGroupMember` for this. A single query to Active Directory asking for any object being a [`memberOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada2/cc24555b-61c7-49a2-9748-167b8ce5a512) any of the groups in the `$GroupArray` already ensures uniqueness and efficiency.

```
$filter = '(|'
$GroupArray | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {
    $filter += '(memberOf={0})' -f $_.DistinguishedName
}
$filter += ')'

# If you want only `user` objects, then change `Get-ADObject` for `Get-ADUser`
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $filter | Select-Object Name |
    Export-Csv 'E:\Software\Powershell Scripts\KB4\KBList.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```